# Remove commas from SAS macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS macro variable that is:

```
&varlist. = OriginCd,DestinCd
```

I'm trying to get a new macro variable that is the same thing, but with the commas removed and a space. So this:

```
&newlist. = OriginCd DestinCd
```

I've tried the following:

```
%let newlist=%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(compbl(&varlist)),%str(,),%str( )));
%let newlist = %sysfunc(compress(&varlist,','));
%let newlist = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&varlist,","," "));
```

For the tranward function, I get "the function TRANWRD referenced by %SYSFUNC macro function has too many arguments". But I'm pretty sure this is how you normally use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
%let varlist=OriginCd,DestinCd;
%let newlist=%sysfunc(compbl(%sysfunc(tranwrd(%quote(&varlist),%str(,),%str( )))));
%put &=newlist;
```

I added `%quote()` to prevent the commas being interpreted as parameter delimeters, and switched the `compbl()` to the outside to prevent the need for another `%quote()`